Composite serial column in mysql
Is it possible to create a serial column based on another column in MySql?
Example table
reg    val    serialval
1       a      1 
1       b      2
2       z      1  
2       x      2
2       y      3 

If I insert another reg 2 the next serialval should be 4, if I insert another reg 1 the next serialval should be 3 if I insert a reg 3 the serial val must be 1 (first occurance of reg 3).
Desired output:
reg    val    serialval
1       a      1 
1       b      2
1       c      3
2       z      1  
2       x      2
2       y      3 
2       a      4
3       k      1

I've tried to create a storage procedure using chatGPT
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_serial INT;

    -- Get the maximum serial value for the current reg
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(serialval), 0) INTO max_serial
    FROM my_table
    WHERE reg = NEW.reg;

    -- Set the serial value to max_serial + 1
    SET NEW.serialval = max_serial + 1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;


Although the above code gives me the following error:
Unknown system variable 'NEW.serialval'

you can add a trigger to do this, however, you can not query the same table you are inserting into in that trigger or you will get a mutation.  This would generally lead you to a new table that contains the 'reg' key from this table, and the count of items that you could query and add 1, or minus one if a row were deleted etc.  However having said that, it is not good normalization to do this at all...  these values can usually be generated at query time and do not need to be stored seperately.

The trigger solution, if it worked, would still create a race condition. That is, two concurrent sessions would try to use the same serialval.

Actually, given that MySQL 8+ now supports window functions, the serialval column can possibly be generated using something like:
SELECT reg, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY reg ORDER BY val) serialval
FROM my_table
ORDER BY 1, 3;

The only issue here is that, going by your sample data, the serialval should reflect the order of insertion of new data, which does not completely line up with the sort order of val.  In this case, we should use this version:
SELECT reg, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY reg ORDER BY id) serialval
FROM my_table
ORDER BY 1, 3;

where perhaps id is some auto incrementing sequence value.

This code works fine:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Get the maximum serial value for the current reg
    SET @max_serial = (select IFNULL(MAX(serialval), 0) FROM my_table WHERE reg = NEW.reg);

    -- Set the serial value to max_serial + 1
    SET NEW.serialval = @max_serial + 1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

